# Is it possible to generate multiple custom vertices using the Bundle Properties from Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, graph, boost

I'm trying to generate an application that solves the bipartite assignment problem via the auction algorithm with the boost graph library. I found it possible to characterize vertices and edges with multiple properties using the [boundle properties](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html). But since the auction algorithm envolve two types of entities, persons and items, I was wondering if there was the possibility of generating more than one characterization of vertices in order to suppor this distinction.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is overly broad, but let me try to provide some helpful pointers.

> But since the auction algorithm [i]nvolve two types of entities, persons and items, I was wondering if there was the possibility of generating more than one characterization of vertices in order to suppor[t] this distinction.

It think "But" can be dropped.

Answering the question, it seems obvious that you can include a type discriminator, like:

```
 struct VertexProperties {
      int multiple;
      std::string characterizing, properties;
      // for auction algorithm:
      bool isPersonEntity;
      // or e.g.
      enum {Person, Item} entityType;
 };
```

Here's several answers that show such classifications in action using BGL:

- using a manual type discriminator like just mentioned: [Boost graph Library using Bundled properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379211/boost-graph-library-using-bundled-properties/46384824#46384824)
- using variant

  1. [Graph with two types of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484144/graph-with-two-types-of-nodes/45504948#45504948)
  2. showing how to use filtered_graph to "view" only part of the vertices at a time: [boost::adjancency_list with polymorphic vertices and edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901822/boostadjancency-list-with-polymorphic-vertices-and-edges/70907765#70907765)
  3. parsing Cars/Planes from XML [Storing a nested XML structure in form of BGL graph using BOOST library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314974/storing-a-nested-xml-structure-in-form-of-bgl-graph-using-boost-library/66319940#66319940)
- using shared pointers (allowing polymorphic property types) [Using boost graph library with a custom class for vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857868/using-boost-graph-library-with-a-custom-class-for-vertices/46858909#46858909)
- alternatives using dynamic property maps [How to use boost::graph dijkstra's algorithm if vertex properties are pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847186/how-to-use-boostgraph-dijkstras-algorithm-if-vertex-properties-are-pointers/41858441#41858441)

Comment: Wow I did't expect such huge answer. [Graph with two types of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484144/graph-with-two-types-of-nodes/45504948#45504948) was what I was loocking for, nevertheless thanks a lot also for the others suggestions!

Comment: If you make the question more focused (e.g. including self-contained exanple) answers can be much shorter :) Glad it was of help